# Using MS Deploy to deploy only the databases

Tags: msdeploy

Can I use MS Deploy to deploy only the databases and not the web applications in the deploy package?

And if so, how?

The website is running on a different server than the databases (web server vs db server) so I'd rather not have it deploy the package in its entirety to the database server.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDeploy does not deploy the entire package to `MsDeploy.axd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273055/is-the-entire-package-uploaded-to-msdeploy-axd), so the deploying the lot just to deploy the database doesn't really have that much overheard.

If you really don't want the website to even be checked for the purposes of synchronization, you have two choices:

1. Deploy the package and skip the iisApp by adding `-skip:objectName=iisApp,setAcl`
2. Split the `dbFullSql` into another package

Either way, I'd recommend continuing to deploy via the application server rather than directly to the database server.